# Using mapping in javascript

Tags: javascript, grails

I want a javascript function for mapping checkbox id with the value of someother field in grails

i have a gsp page with checkbox and cost field as follows

```
<td>
                    <g:checkBox type="checkbox" class="select_all" name="counTestUnit" id="${testUnitInstance.id}" />
                    </td>


                    <td>
                        <g:textField name="cost"  maxlength="20" required="" id="${testUnitInstance.id}"  />
                    </td>
```

i want a javascript function with mapping between checked checkbox id with cost field

Comment: bit un clear , ? how do you compare means? check box has boolean  value and text field will have a string value ?

Comment: checkbox will have individual id and text field will have integer value,,,,,,, using checked checkbox id i want to select corresponding cost value

Comment: aha clear then ,i guess!

Answer (score 0):

you need a on change function for the check box and add intital for the id to diffrentiate it the cost text field,since intital follows ID later on you extract that ID and find the corresponding cost field.

```
"c_${testUnitInstance.id}"
```

example

```
<g:checkBox type="checkbox" class="select_all" name="counTestUnit" id="c_${testUnitInstance.id}" onChange="FindCost('c_${testUnitInstance.id}')"/>

<g:javascript>    

function FindCost(chckboxname){  
console.log("check Status:"+$("#"+chckboxname).prop("checked"));
var arrayOfchckBoxId = chckboxname.split("_"); //parse the two parts of the name after _

var commnidforcheckandcost = arrayOfchckBoxId[1];

var initialname = arrayOfchckBoxId[0];

var currentCheckbox = "#"+chckboxname ;

console.log("ID:"+arrayOfchckBoxId[1]);
console.log("Name:"+currentCheckbox);

if(initialname == 'c'){
//display the corresponsing cost text field.

$("#"+commnidforcheckandcost").show() //display the cost with a give id like checkbox

 }

</g:javascript>
```

i guess this should resolve your problem for more help see ,the javascript console debug.

Comment: danielad i already have javascript function for retrieving checkbox which is checked i.e,jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  alert("checking for checkbox");
  jQuery('#groupdelete').on('click', function(){
    var names = [];
    alert("*********");
   jQuery('input:checked').each(function() {
    var cost = document.getElementById('costId').value;
    alert(cost);
     alert("comes in");
       names.push(jQuery(this).attr("id"));
       
   });
   
     alert(names); 
  })

  }) here i want to get the corresponding cost value for that specific id

Comment: @oh what a waste then ? it may help some one then ? i didn;t get your question exactly :(

Answer (score 0):

You can do as below

```
<td>
                    <g:checkBox type="checkbox" class="select_all" name="counTestUnit" id="checkbox${testUnitInstance.id}" onclick="mapCheckAndField(${testUnitInstance.id})"/>
                    </td>


                    <td>
                        <g:textField name="cost"  maxlength="20" required="" id="textField${testUnitInstance.id}"  />
                    </td>
<script>
function mapCheckAndField(testUnitId)
{
   //we know that now checkboxId is "checkbox"+testUnitId
   //and corresponding textField id is "textField"+testUnitId
   //Simply you will get the value of checkbox corresponding textField value as below
   $("#textField"+testUnitId).val()
}
</script>
```